# Get Key and values from JSONObject using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

How do i get list of object from this online json

JSON

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "Chandler M Bing",
    "winning_rate": "80"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "Ted Mosby",
    "winning_rate": "78.5"
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "John Cena",
    "winning_rate": "76.5"
  },
  "4": {
    "name": "John Snow",
    "winning_rate": "56.2"
  },
  "5": {
    "name": "Khal Drogo",
    "winning_rate": "79.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far

Comment: i am using @Get("players.json")Call<List<Player>> getAllPlayers; but it showing me this error Retrofit: D/Response: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Your response not List it's Json. List response showed in `[` and Json Data shown in `{`

Comment: Thank You soo much..I sloved my problem using @GET("participant.json")
    Flowable<Map<String, Players>> getAllPlayer();

Comment: provide your expected result